# rstudioapi::viewer programmatic deletion option

Tags: r, rstudio

The [`rstudioapi::viewer`](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioapi/reference/viewer.html) can render static html pages from temp directory as given in the following example.

```r
dir <- tempfile()
dir.create(dir)
htmlFile <- file.path(dir, "index.html")
writeLines(
  '<h1 style="text-align: center;">Thank you for using <span style="color: #ff0000;">Tidycells</span></h1>
<p style="text-align: center;">It is an <span style="color: #ff6600;"><strong>assistant</strong> </span>for you</p>
<p style="text-align: center;">It is <span style="text-decoration: underline;">yet to <span style="color: #0000ff; text-decoration: underline;">evolve</span></span></p>',
  htmlFile
)
suppressWarnings(rstudioapi::viewer(htmlFile))
```

However, I could not delete a viewer object using R code.

screenshot

[image]

If anyone clicks the delete button ("Remove current viewer item") the current item will be deleted.

I was looking for a programmatic way to do it.

Maybe `rstudioapi::viewer(htmlFile)` will return an `id` and that can be used to delete the specific item from the viewer pane.

Comment: Added an issue here https://github.com/rstudio/rstudioapi/issues/169

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it like this

```
runApp_nb <- function(sa, pin_port = NULL){


  viewer <- getOption("viewer")
  if(!is.null(viewer)){

    if(!is.null(pin_port) && is.integer(pin_port)){
      port <- pin_port
    }else{
      port <- as.integer(sample(3000:49000, 1))
    }

    x <- callr::r_bg(function(x, y){shiny::runApp(x, port = y)}, args = list(sa , port))
    viewer(paste0("http://localhost:",port,"/"))
    return(invisible(x))
  }

  cat("\nThis is designed for RStudio\n")

  return(invisible(0))

}
```

Then

```
x <- runApp_nb(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Finally after operation

```
x$kill_tree()
```